# Building a set of sets with different sizes

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Let $n$ be a positive integer and $N$ be a set of ordered sets that meet some condition, whose size goes from $1$ to $n$. My question is how to write this downs by using set-builder notation. Here go my attempts:

- $N = \{(a_1, \ldots, a_m) \in \mathbb{R}^m \mid m \in \{1, \ldots, n\} \text{ and some condition}\}$
- $N = \{(a_1, \ldots, a_{n - m}) \in \mathbb{R}^{n-m} \mid m \in \{0, \ldots, n - 1\} \text{ and some condition}\}$

I think both options are essentially the same, maybe the latter being unnecessarily complicated, but I wonder if they capture that $N$ must contain **all** those sets of size less or equal to $n$ that meet the condition.

Comment: This way the elements of $N$ are actually tuples. Do you identify "tuples" as "ordered sets"?

Comment: @drhab Yes, as long as they can be used in the condition in their order, i.e., $\text{condition} := f(a_1, \ldots, a_m) = 0$

Comment: Are there objections against defining $S:=\cup_{k=1}^n\mathbb R^k$ to go on with $N=\{s\in S\mid P(s)\}$ where $P$ stands for a property?

Comment: @drhab No objections at all :) Thank you!

Comment: @drhab One question though: what if the property is defined by means of a function $f(a_1, \ldots, a_m)$, $m \in \{1, \ldots, n\}$? I mean, how to define $P$? Something like $P(s) = f(s_1, \ldots, s_m)$?

Comment: If one function $f$ determines the property then all tuples are forced to be elements of the domain of that function. So if the length of the tuples is truly variable then you cannot do with a function having e.g. $\mathbb R^m$ as domain. My solution only works if you are able to construct a function on the set $S$ that determines the property.

Comment: @drhab And could the domain of $f$ be $\bigcup_{k = 1}^n \mathbb{R}^k$?

Comment: In principle every set can be domain of a function. The question is more: can it be constructed is such a way that $P(s)$ can be formulated in terms of $f(s)$? This is questionable and the reason why I started with: "are there objections..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @drhab indicated, set builder notation, $\{x \in X : P(x)\}$ requires a set $X$ and a condition $P(x)$ on elements $x \in X$. So you need something like

$$\left\{ x \in \bigcup_{i=1}^n \mathbb R^i : P(x) \right\}$$